# I don't have permission for anything! please help

Tags: 11.10, permissions, gnome-classic, gvfs

Running Ubuntu 11.10 in gnome classic, I just changed it to make gnome classic the auto login choice and now I cannot delete files, save files, or anything. I tried using the command:

```
sudo chown -R user:user /home/user
```

Only to get this response....

```
chown: cannot access `/home/user/.gvfs': Permission denied
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is only my 3rd day ever using linux

Comment: does it work, when you switch to superuser (sudo su) and then invoke the chmod command?

Comment: I tried typing "sudo su" instead of just "sudo" and it said that it was an invalid option. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Do you have an encrypted home folder?

Answer (score 4):

`/home/user/.gvfs` is the mount point for a virtual filesystem used by Gnome. It cannot be accessed by any other user than the session owner (not even root) while a Gnome session is active.

By default `chown` only prints error messages so if you don't get any other response from `chown` that means everything else worked fine.

If you still can't create or delete files in your home folder please post the output of the following commands:

```
ls -ld ~/
touch ~/this_is_just_a_test_file
rm -v ~/this_is_just_a_test_file
```

Comment: user@ubuntu:~$ ls -ld ~/
drwxr-xr-x 35 user user 4096 2011-11-14 15:02 /home/user/
user@ubuntu:~$ touch ~/this_is_just_a_test_file
user@ubuntu:~$ rm -v ~/this_is_just_a_test_file
removed `/home/user/this_is_just_a_test_file'

Comment: But I still cannot delete files off of my desktop that I put  there, cannot save any files of any type except I guess for when I am in terminal? I don't understand

Comment: How do you try to save a file? Into which folder do you want to save it?

Comment: I cannot save into any folder, ie. Desktop, Pictures, Videos, anything. It says that the file already exists and asks me to replace it, then if I try to replace it says permission denied. And I have never saved anything to any folder, so obviously the new files don't exist

Comment: Okay... So is there a command that overrides this? Equivalent of takeown in win10?

Comment: P.S. This would not be such a big problem if gvfs-mount respected the allow_root options passed to gvfsd-fuse.  Just saying...  I guess there's always Win10 if this fails

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by going to the properties of each folder in my Home folder, and changing the permissions to 'Create and Delete'. They were set to "no access'. So I guess it was a pretty simple solution, maybe there is an easier way? Thanks for everyone trying to help this noob.

Answer (score 1):

Stupid question: did you change "user", using instead your user name?

Try: 
`sudo chown -vR user /home/user`

so you can see what happened.

ps my .[gvfs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GVFS) is empty, and the .something are configuration files. You can delete it, if you didn't need the actual configuration (3rd day, I bet you didn't configure it ;):

`sudo rm -fvr /home/user/.gvfs`

Comment: @ Roland Taylor cannot remove `/home/user/.gvfs': Is a directory    btw, my username is user lol